# Get code from String C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string and need to convert this string into code.

```
string s = "Method1";
string s_1 = "()";
s = s + s_1;
switch ((irrelevant))
{
    case 1:      
       (i need the string to code here to enable the Mehod1)
       break;
}

void Method1()
{
}
```

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: You *can* do this sort of thing with reflection, but there's almost certainly a better way to solve your problem. If you explain your actual goal, we can probably suggest something easier/better.

Comment: do you mean run a text string dynamically as code? like if your string was printf('hello world");

Comment: Can you give more background information on this?  This is getting into more advance topics with reflection and the emit method to generate this code and I'm not sure this is the best place to start if you are just starting.  Probably a better way to do this too unless you are making your own psuedo compiler.

Comment: I have many options and they are called the same as the Methods they are linked to. So i dont know what method the user will choose so it would be best if i get the method from the string.

Comment: We have no idea what it is that you need, the question is not clear.

Comment: I just need the text in the string in code so the string is "Method()" And i need it in code

Comment: There are a few Reflection.emit, Scripting, and also IronRuby/Iron Python. But if you are just doing basic arithmetic, and expression parser might be better.

Comment: This is almost **never** a good idea, especially in C#. There are better, safer, faster ways to do this. Perhaps with more details of what you're trying to do, we can suggest something.

Comment: @user2684089 you better use a scripting language. As far as I understand from your question and comments, you haven't got the enough knowledge to use *reflection*, unless someone writes the whole code for you. Is this what you expect?....

Comment: @user2684089 I've had a similar problem, my solution was to create a hashtable-equivalent of strings and delegates, and then when I take an input, look up the string's method in the hashtable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using reflection you can invoke the method by name (by name without parenthesis) just with the name.

this solution must be accepted if just if you need execute a method by name

example, if your method is named `Method1` in the same class named `ClassWithMethods`

```
Type type = typeof(ClassWithMethods);
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Method1");
result = methodInfo.Invoke(this, null);
```

the first parameter of invoke I use this because it's running the same intance but this parameter ask for the object on which to invoke the method or constructor. If a method is static, this argument is ignored. If a constructor is static, this argument must be null or an instance of the class that defines the constructor

Comment: I think this goes a long way in answering the question, but I personally don't understand the text after the code. Please rewrite. It would also be a good idea to use the variables in the question (e.g. I presume the `"methodName"` would be equivalent to `s` without the parentheses.

Comment: Afraid not this would be write a method that does a = b+ c, then call it with the arguments. In other words you'd have to write all the code you might want to run in advance. It's not hard, though for a piece of code this trivial seems to be overkill, and you do have to know what is in the brackets to set it all up.

Comment: answer updated, and yes @owlstead would be equivalent to s without the parentheses